# Use leveldb-library.framework from firebase for iOS with Xcode9

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase, xcode9, leveldb

I would like to be able to use the leveldb-library.framework that google is shipping with their firebase iOS SDK. I don't seem to be able to import the framework.

What I did: 
1: copy leveldb-library.framework to project dir
2: in Xcode > Target > Linked Frameworks and Libraries [+] add the framework
[image: screenshot1]

3: make sure the header search path it set correctly
[image: screenshot2]

4: add a Objective-C++ wrapper class and import the leveldb headers
[image: screeenshot3]

Getting a linker error:

```
/Users/ronny/projects/clients/internal/TestCD/TestCD/LevelDB.mm:11:9: fatal error: 'leveldb/db.h' file not found
#import "leveldb/db.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The Headers directory in the framework provides all the headers: db.h, options.h but without the "leveldb" parent directory.

Changing the imports to the following throws the same error:

```
#import <leveldb/db.h>
#import <leveldb/options.h>
```

Once I change the imports to this:

```
#import <leveldb-library/db.h>
#import <leveldb-library/options.h>
```

the linker is able to find the includes but throws another error:

[image: screenshot4]

```
In file included from /Users/ronny/projects/clients/internal/TestCD/TestCD/LevelDB.mm:11:
/Users/ronny/projects/clients/internal/TestCD/leveldb-library.framework/Headers/db.h:10:10: fatal error: 'leveldb/iterator.h' file not found
#include "leveldb/iterator.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

At this point I am no longer sure what can be done in order to resolve this. Adding the import path doesn't help either. Xcode completes the import as such:

[image: screenshot5]

Any pointers towards solving this would be greatly appreciated. The project can be found here: https://github.com/ronnyf/TestCD

Comment: I have also face this issue. You should import this framework on embedded binaries. Like follow this step: Xcode > Target > Genral > Embedded Binaries and Libraries [+] add the framework. Clean project and run.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This unfortunately does not resolve the issue. The compiler still complains 'leveldb/db.h' file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework expects to be called `leveldb`, but your example calls it `leveldb-library`.

```
mv leveldb-library.framework leveldb.framework
mv leveldb.framework/leveldb-library leveldb.framework/leveldb
```

Update the Xcode project with the renamed framework and it successfully builds.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for the quick answer. It works of course as you suggested. I was hoping I could re-use the leveldb-library.framework I already have linked to my project using the firebase iOS sdk.

Comment: It should be possible - just a bit more complicated with munging Xcode options. You could take a look at how CocoaPods does project set up to enable access to leveldb-library - or post another sample project that includes Firebase to github and I'll take a look.

Comment: After renaming the framework, I added the umbrella header that cocoapods generated to the headers directory and added the firebase frameworks. I was able to retrieve data from the realtime db. Your help is greatly appreciated. If you want to take a look, it should all be in the repo.